# Clipping Magic API

Tags: javascript, function

I am currently trying to use the api for [clippingmagic](https://clippingmagic.com/api/)  but I am running into a problem with defining their callback function. Here is the code I have currently for it.

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://clippingmagic.com/api/v1/ClippingMagic.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var errorsArray = ClippingMagic.initialize({apiId: ####});
  if (errorsArray.length > 0) alert("Sorry, your browser is missing some required features: \n\n " + errorsArray.join("\n "));
  ClippingMagic.edit({
    "image" : {
      "id" : ######,
      "secret" : "#############"
    }
  }, callback);
  </script>
```

If anyone has worked with their api and can help me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you defining your `callback` variable? I don't see that `callback` would actually resolve to a function that you've defined.

```
ClippingMagic.edit({
    "image" : {
        "id" : response.image_id,
        "secret" : response.image_secret
    }
}, function(response) {

    if(response.event == 'result-generated') {
        # response.image.id
        # response.image.image_secret
    }

});
```

I created a clipping magic plugin for WordPress to edit WooCommerce product photos and this is a snippet from it.